# Excel Consolidating Text String (Yes/No)

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, vba

Trying to combine the data into one master sheet. I have something like below:

```
Sheet 1                Sheet 2                 Sheet 3
Name    Gain(Y/N)      Name    Gain(Y/N)       Name    Gain(Y/N)   
AAA     Y              AAA     Y               AAA     
BBB     N              BBB                     BBB     N
CCC                    CCC     Y               CCC     Y
DDD                    DDD                     DDD     Y
EEE                    EEE                     EEE     N
```

Ultimately would look something like (merging all the sheets into sheet1)

```
Sheet 1                
Name    Gain(Y/N)         
AAA     Y                   
BBB     N              
CCC     Y               
DDD     Y               
EEE     N
```

The problem is that consolidate function won't work for Text string (Y/N)

I am thinking something like 'if vlookup' or match index? but for multiple reference? 
and not overriding each other. Maybe there is simpler way...

Thanks for your help :D

Comment: Can you show what you want "consolidated" data to look like? What do you do if different sheets give different results (e.g. on sheet1, `AAA --> Y`, and on sheet3, `AAA --> N`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=IF(OR(Sheet1!B2="Y",Sheet2!B2="Y",Sheet3!B2="Y"),"Y",IF(OR(Sheet1!B2="N",Sheet2!B2="N",Sheet3!B2="N"),"N",""))
```

in `B2` of a new sheet and copied down may suit.

*Edit* Simplification of revised formula to reflect edit to question:

Filter Sheet1 for Gain (Y/N) (assumed to be ColumnB) for (Blanks) and in the cell with the smallest visible row number enter:

```
=IF(OR(VLOOKUP(A4,Sheet2!A:B,2,0)="Y",VLOOKUP(A4,Sheet3!A:B,2,0)="Y"),"Y",IF(OR(VLOOKUP(A4,Sheet2!A:B,2,0)="N",VLOOKUP(A4,Sheet3!A:B,2,0)="N"),"N",""))
```

Change `4`s in `A4`s to smallest visible row number (adjust column references as necessary) and copy down as required.

Comment: thank you for the input, but would this only work for the sheets that are perfectly matched and sorted by rows?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind creating an extra column on each sheet, you could turn "Y" and "N" into a number. Assuming your labels are in column A, you insert a new column B and put the following in B2:

```
=IF(A2="Y", 3, IF(A2="N", 2, 1))
```

Repeat for all sheets. Now you can do consolidation, using the "MAX" function. It will return `2` if the letter `"Y"` appeared anywhere, etc.  Now you can get back to Y/N/blank by putting the following formula in a column next to the consolidated data:

```
=INDEX({" ","N","Y"}, B2)
```

This will return `" "` if `B2` is `1`, `"N"` if `B2` is `2`, etc. Finally you can copy the entire column, and "paste special - values" to get exactly what you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

You might as well use [Microsoft Query](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/use-microsoft-query-to-retrieve-external-data-HA010099664.aspx) to fetch all the data into a pivot with a code similar to this:

```
SELECT Name, Gain, 'Sheet1' as [Sheet#]
FROM Sheet1
UNION
SELECT Name, Gain, 'Sheet2' as [Sheet#]
FROM Sheet2
UNION
SELECT Name, Gain, 'Sheet3' as [Sheet#]
FROM Sheet3
```